# Road Distance Calculation using GPS Co-ordinate

Tags: gps, distance

[Path image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqJ0C.png)

I need to calculate distance from subscriber position to Position B in the image. I have the GPS co-ordinate of the subscriber and the "B" position. How can I calculate the distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple case:  Express lat and long values in decimal form and use the standard geometry distance formula if subscriber is less than 100 miles from position B.  distance = sqrt((lat1-lat2)^2 - (long1-long2)^2).

More general case:  Use the haversine formulas using a great circle to calculate distances from points on a sphere for more accurate measurements if position B might be a continent or two away from the subscriber.  Let's call the subscriber position A and say and say he is at lat[a], long[a] and the fixed point B is at lat[b], long[b].  Let r represent the radius of the earth (about 3961 miles).

distance = 2*r*arcsin(sqrt(sin^2((lat[b]-lat[a])/2) + cos(lat[a])*cos(lat[b])*sin^2((long[b]-long[a])/2)))

If you specify r in miles, your answer will come out in miles.  If you use kilometers use 6373 for a good number for the earth's radius, and of course the answer will come out in kilometers.

Exact case:  The haversine formula will not provide a perfect answer because the earth is not a perfect sphere.  Even apart from the mountains and the canyons, the earth has a larger radius at the equator than it does at the poles.  The radius at the equator is the equator is about 3963 miles, and at the poles it is about 3950 miles.  So you really need to devise your own lookup table (or borrow one from google maps) if you are measuring distances halfway around the globe and you have to be exact.

The haversine formula will be accurate to less than half of a percentage point.  In 1000 miles your answer will be accurate to within 5 miles.

Haversine formula:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Radius of the earth:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius